# Why am I getting that my thread exits before anything in `Main` can run?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a simple console application

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ConsoleApplicationFont
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("At least we got here");//TEST
            try
            {
                var FF = new FontFamily();
                foreach (var item in FF.FamilyNames.Keys) 
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is currently outputting

> The thread 0x1b9c has exited with code 259 (0x103). The thread 0x2438
>   has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x444 has exited with code
>   259 (0x103). The thread 0x21ec has exited with code 259 (0x103). The
>   thread 0x266c has exited with code 259 (0x103). The program '[7564]
>   SeeSystemDotDrawingFonts.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

and the output doesn't have anything to do with the body of `Main` because I get it even if it all out. What is the problem here and how can I debug these types of situations?

Comment: there will be plenty of threads in the background - one for the finalizer, etc. - I would not worry about them

Comment: I think you are looking for your output in the wrong place... heh...

Comment: From MSDN: "Use this default constructor when you want to create a composite font programmatically. This means that you do not have to specify a font family name for the constructor, but you must populate the collections in the FamilyMaps and FamilyNames collections prior to using the constructed instance." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602322%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'd have expected a compiler warning since FontFamily is defined both in System.Drawing and in System.Windows.Media

Comment: @devio Not warning,error.This code cannot compile

Comment: @Subpar Web Dev What exaclty do you want to accomplish?How is this different from your previous question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("At least we got here");//TEST
            try
            {
                var  installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();
                var fontFamilies = installedFontCollection.Families;
                var count = fontFamilies.Length;
                for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fontFamilies[j].Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yf5t4e8(v=vs.110).aspx